# Dotted border from left to right (between two elements)

Tags: css, html

I have no idea how to do this one.

What I want to do is print dots between Uncategorized and 82,359, or at least the illusion, i guess i have to do something with a dotted border

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="count">82,359</span>
        Uncategorized
    </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS

```
.list a {
display: block;
padding: 6px 10px;
}

.list .count {
font-weight: normal;
float: right;
color: #6b7a8c;
}
```

What I want is this:

[image: what i want]
What I've tried, and the only way i can think of is `<div style="border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC;"></div>` between .count and Uncategorized, but that add the border on top of the two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the example used here: [**Dot Leaders**](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html) as referenced by Black Hat Samurai, slight change to the markup and the CSS from the link helped it.

Added comments to explain how the code works.

```css
ul.list {
  max-width: 220px; /* Set the width for the whole list */
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul.list li:before {
  float: left; /* Let the before pseudo element start from the leftmost position of each list item */ 
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  content: ".....................................................";
  color: #ccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul.list span:first-child {
  background: white; 
  padding-right: 0.2em;
}
ul.list span + span {
  float: right; /* Align the count to the rightmost position of the list */
  background: white;
  padding-left: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <a href="#">

      <span class="title">Uncategorized</span>
      <span class="count">82,359</span>

    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ofcourse, you will need to edit the values based on corresponding change of parent. This was based on your code. Also please edit the swear word in your comment.

Comment: i got it working, thanks a bunch. i cant seem to edit my comment

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with something like this

```css
.list {
  min-width:15em;
}
.first {
  float:left;
  margin-right:0.5em;
  color:#2B91AF
}
.price {
  float:right;
  margin-left:0.5em;
  width:4em;
  text-align: right;
}
.list:after {
  content:'';
   border-bottom:dotted 2px tomato;
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:0.8em;
}
```

```html
<p class="list">
  <i class='first'>Co-Pay:</i>
  <i class="price">$150.00</i> 
</p>
<p class="list">
  <i class='first'>Pay:</i>
  <i class="price"> $5.00</i> 
</p>
<p class="list">
  <i class='first'>Co-Pay: item</i>
  <i class="price"> $15.00</i> 
</p>
<p class="list">
  <i class='first'>Co-Pay: great deal</i>
  <i class="price"> $1.00</i> 
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

With flex it's really easy now :

```
<div class="parent">
    <span class="description">Description</span>
    <div class="dottedDiv"></div>
    <span class="price">price</span>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.parent {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

.description{
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.price{
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.dottedDiv{
 height : 1.6rem;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
 flex-grow: 2;
 }
```

Note that I'm reducing the height of the dotted div, to have the line exactly where I want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called Dot Leaders. Here is an article that describes how you achieve the desire effect:

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html

Comment: A link only answer is not a good answer. Post some examples from source, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .list a {
            display: block;
            border-bottom: dotted 1px;
            height: 13px;
        }

        .list .title {
            padding-right: 5px;
            background-color: white;
            font-weight: normal;
            float: left;
            color: #6b7a8c;
        }
        .list .count {
            background-color: white;
            padding-left: 5px;
            font-weight: normal;
            float: right;
            color: #6b7a8c;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="list">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="title">Uncategorized</span>
            <span class="count">82,359</span>
        </a>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I used a dirty hack. First of all,  tag now has a height 13. Then I added background-color: white (or whatever) to remove dots under the text. Please be careful of using this solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

HTML

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>
    <a href="#">
        <span>Uncategorized</span>
        <span class="count">82,359</span>
    </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 17px;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
ul.list li{
}
li span + span:before{
    content: "..................................";
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zo6dv6m/)